# Cast with getType() function C#

Tags: c#, interface, casting

There are a lot solutions, but it doesn't work, as i need. So problem is:
I have a form class:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form , InterfaceConsole
  { 
    Imperx cam;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cam = new Imperx(this);

    }
         ...
  }
```

I have my own class called Imperx:

```
class Imperx
  {
     private InterfaceConsole imperx_Form;
     private Form form;

     public Imperx(Form form){
         this.form = form;
         imperx_Form = (?????)form;
     }
```

So, I want to cast my form variable to interface, that implemented in Form1 class, but i want to do it without cast to Form1? As i understand, it's useful for me to use form.getType() function, but it says that cannot implicity System.type to *my_namespace*.InterfaceConsole.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to pass in a `Form1` instance? I don't see why you need to cast at all

Comment: How can you cast it without casting? - "I want to cast my form variable to interface, that implemented in Form1 class, but i want to do it without cast to Form1?". You will need to perform casting either from class to interface or from interface to class.

Comment: @Sayse I need it, becasuse i want to do universal class. I don't exactly what name of class, that will implemented my interface.

Comment: @user3418460 - Great ok, then just pass in an `InterfaceConsole`, Your class already has a dependency on making sure that the form you pass in implements this

Comment: @Sayse Sorry, i don't understand what do u mean? Can u please give me an example?

Comment: `public Imperx(InterfaceConsole iconsole)`

Comment: @Sayse Ok, thanks. It's simple way. Good. Bu what concerns about my way. How can i get name of my class form to cast it?

Comment: @user3418460 - You can't and for good reason, You can't guarrantee that the instance of form that is being passed in is a subclass that implements that interface.

Comment: @Sayse I'm sure, that this class will implement my interface. It's just interest to make so, as i described.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is right. Since you are passing a Form, there is no implicit conversion to `InterfaceConsole`.

You can check with the operator `is` whether form is of type `InterfaceConsole` and then cast it. Or directly cast it to it and check for nullity.

You could fix `Imperx` by passing Form1 types instead of Form type, then implicit conversion will be available.

How ever without knowing the scenario none of these approaches look good as you are creating dependencies between all classes here.

Comment: I need it, becasuse i want to do universal class. I don't exactly what name of class, that will implemented my interface.

Comment: @user3418460 this is far from being a complete sentence that makes sense. And an `universal class` sounds pretty much like a god class in your approach.